# How to output inverted matches using the jq command-line JSON processor?

Tags: json, jq, negation

Is it possible to output inverted matches using the [jq command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? The tool `grep` supports the option `-v, --invert-match: select non-matching lines` for this.

As an example, I'm searching for a command such as the following. However, `without(...)` doesn't exist:

```sh
$  echo '{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}' | jq '. | without(c)' 
{
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1
}
```

- There is no program option such as `grep -v` for `jq`.
- I failed to find a [basic filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) for this.

Are inverted matches supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question, I found the [builtin `del(path_expression)` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) which solves the issue:

> The builtin function del removes a key and its corresponding value from an object.

```sh
$ echo '{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}' | jq 'del(.c)'
{
  "a": 0,
  "b": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

jq is generally quite minimalist, so when in doubt while looking for the opposite of something, `not` is always available to come to the rescue, e.g.

```
with_entries(select(.key == "c"|not))
```

The thing that's probably unfamiliar here is that `not` in jq is a normal 0-arity filter.

Of course `!=` is also supported:

```
with_entries(select(.key != "c"))
```

Since you mentioned `grep`, it may be worth noting that the jq "equivalent" of `grep -v "REGEX"` would be `test("REGEX")|not`.

Incidentally, that initial `. |` in your first attempt would not be necessary.